# Movie with human-likes turning into a galaxy cloud (±2010 or later)

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for a movie of which I can only really remember one scene.

Two (what appear to be) humans meet with some alien race (the aliens kind of look like ants with armour and are no bigger than your hand). The humans asks the messenger ant-like to kill/assasinate someone from a certain species. The messenger turns around to look/talk to their queen after which he turns back to say something along the lines of "We do not partake in the killing of <Species> or assist in the killing thereof". Right then the two human-likes look angry and turn into a sort of galaxy cloud as a threat.

I don't remember much more from the movie. I think it had like a black market, shady business kind of vibe to it. the special effects looked quite good so I reckon the movie can't be released before 2010 at least

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this film?

Comment: @LogicDictates I think like a year, maybe a year and a half, ago.

Comment: ±2010: The movie was made in either 2010 AD or 2010 BC, we don't remember which :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like [Men in Black: International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black:_International). (2019)

The small ant-like creature (voiced by Kumail Nanjiani) that reports to its queen who refuse to kill would be Pawney:

> As clearly stated in section 6C of the Treaty of Andromeda II, we do
> not kill Jababians nor participate in the murder thereof. This is non-negotiable.

[image: Small creature standing on chessboard with a spear or wand.]

<sup>Copyright Sony Pictures 2019, from [The Nerdy.com](https://thenerdy.com/men-in-black-international-trailer/), fair usage.</sup>

The Two human-like creature that turn into "galaxies" members of "The Hive" species, played by Laurent and Larry Bourgeois, would be the "mysterious alien twins able to manifest as pure energy":

[image: Two mean-looking dudes with special effects.]

<sup>Copyright Sony Pictures 2019, via [Sneekpeek.ca](http://www.sneakpeek.ca/2019/06/men-in-black-international-universe-is.html), fair usage.</sup>

Comment: Yes!! That's the movie I was thinking of. Thanks so much for the help!